# How to base new email-less Outlook profile on old *.pst file?

Tags: pst, microsoft-outlook-2019

I bought and installed Outlook 2019 to use as my Personal Information Manager (PIM) without putting the information in the cloud.  This is how I used Outlook 2007 and 2010.  One account acted as an offline PIM while another served as an IMAP account.

I created an email-less profile in Outlook 2019 using `Outlook.exe /PIM NoEmail`.  It is associated with a `*.pst` file.  I additionally opened my `*.pst` from Outlook 2007, where all my stuff is.  In the Account Settings, I set the latter as my default data file.

I then selected the first `*.pst` file and tried to remove it. No matter how many times I try, and how long I wait, all I get is "You cannot delete this Outlook data file.  Configuration information in the file is being copied to your new default data file.  You can delete the file after this information is copied".

It has been a half hour now, and my `*.pst` file from Outlook 2007 is less than 30MB.  What is really preventing me from deleting the `*.pst` file created with `Outlook.exe /PIM NoEmail`?

Comment: What happens if you move or delete the actual file, can you delete the file, after the error that will be generated after Outlook can’t find the file?

Comment: I'd like to hold off on that for now. Having made the old `*.pst` file the default, the profile is no longer considered email-less. I am prompted to sign in when starting Outlook. This, despite the fact that I didn't have an email account associated with old `*.pst` file.  I will have the set the default data file to the one created with `Outlook.exe /PIM NoEmail`.

Comment: This means that, rather than switching to my old `*.pst` file to access my stuff, I have to copy or import all my stuff over to the newly created `*.pst` file.  I remember having terrible surprises from that, e.g., all the calendar subject lines prefixed with "Copy of" or some such.  In Month view, that prefix takes up all the available viewing space, and none of the information in the original subject line shows.  I also remember having to answer the same prompt question a gazillion times, one for each appointment.

Microsoft doesn't make simple things easy.

Comment: Eureka!  Importing does the job with none of the issues described above.  Those issues must result from copying rather than importing.

Answer (score 0):

Importing from the old `*.pst` file into the new one did the job.  It caused none of the problems like prefixing all calendar items with "Copy of" and prompting the user a gazillion times with the same question (one per Outlook item).